# Is there a way to access the cell that is shown the most in a CollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to modify the design of my UICollectionView based on the cell that is seen at any given time. Meaning that if I have a first cell, and then half of another one, I'd like to access and modify the one that the user is likely focusing on, which is the complete one.

Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Please see attachment (In this case, I'd like to programmatically change the cell that says Pirkei Avot):

[image: In this case, I'd like to programmatically leave the blue bar in the cell that says Pirkei Avot, and hide it from the other ones]

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( UICollectionViewCell *cell in theCollectionView.visibleCells) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectIntersection(theCollectionView.frame, cell.frame);
    //check width of each cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is only called once assuming I put it in viewDidLoad or some other func. How could the program update once a different cell becomes visible?

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView